# How do I get my Ionic/React app to read/load my .env file?

Tags: reactjs, npm, ionic-framework, dotenv, ionic7

I'm using Ionic 7, React 18, and included dotenv 16.3.  I have created a blank ionic application and have added a file alongside package.json (.env)

```
NODE_ENV=local
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

I have also created a file, src/services.api.ts, which contains

```
$ cat src/services/api.ts 
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
});
```

However, attempting to load this file results in a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    <anonymous> api.ts:4
```

error when I access the app after starting it using

```
ionic serve
```

What else do I need to do to get ionic to read my .env file?

Comment: _"included dotenv 16.3"_ how? Your `api.ts` is presumably running client-side, the way e.g. CRA (**not** just React generally) [does this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) is to use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to replace literal appearances of `process.env.REACT_APP_VAR` in source code with the relevant value - do you have something like that set up? `process` is [in the Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#process), but that code isn't running in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Vite to build your app.
Vite doesn't use Webpack, and therefore, the usual Webpack globals like process aren't available by default.

Vite exposes env variables on the special `import.meta.env` object.

Here's their detailed instruction: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: Thanks ,changing the .env property to "VITE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000" and using "mport.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL" solved the problem.

Comment: it took my hours. Chat GTP didnt even suggest it